# Future tense, will, will have

Tags: grammaticality

What is the difference between following sentences:

1. She will reach there by Monday next.
2. She will have reached there by Monday next.

Comment: Not a great deal of difference, really: 1. focuses on her journey up to the point of arrival, while 2. focuses on her situation on or shortly after arrival.

Comment: "Monday next" is literary usage. Normally it is "next Monday".

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the difference in this way:

> She will reach there by Monday next.

*Today, we anticipate that she will arrive there by next Monday.*

And now the future perfect:

> She will have reached there by Monday next.

*Next Monday, we will be able to say "She has arrived".*

or

*Next Monday, the statement "She has arrived" will be true.*

With the future perfect, we are *projecting* ourselves into the future and referring to her arrival from that projected point in time.